# Is there a connector/c++ library which does not require boost?

Tags: c++, boost, mysql-connector

I'm using connector/c++.

It'll be fine if I include boost (or a part of it), but it's too large.
A full lib is about 100MB, I tried to remove unused files, then it comes about 12MB, which is still too large.

In addition, I guess it loads more dlls that are unnecessary.

So, it there a connector/c++ library which doest not require boost?

Comment: You can tune what library you include, thus if the remaining libs are 12mb then it may be required :)

Comment: @Geoffroy: There is not any other way to do, is it?

Comment: Is the compiled code too large? Compilers will often not include unused code in the final executable.

Comment: @DavidBrown: I use it for all team, thus it's a copying/transfering issue... Anyway, if there is no way, I'll live with it :D

Comment: @H3S: You don't need to copy the libs every time, just install them once which means that even if it is *large* the cost is a one time off thing, part of setting up the development environment.

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for a library for connecting to MySQL?
You should try OTL (http://otl.sourceforge.net/). It works with MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle etc..
And you just have to include one header, quite light.
Tell me if that annswers your needs.

Comment: Thank you very much! That project is working well so I don't want to change it. I'll try your recommendation on some new project.

Answer (score 0):

Check libdrizzle (https://launchpad.net/libdrizzle). 
As far as I know, it needs Boost only for unit testing (a part which probably can be stripped out).